# Multiple copy/paste on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, copy-paste

Does windows 8 have a multiple copy/paste facility, or is it still one piece of content allowed to be copied at a time? If so, how can I have multiple copy/paste with different shortcuts if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean? what are you trying to copy? you have always been able to copy multiples of anything at once.

Comment: I mean what I ask, multiple and different pieces of content to different buffers!

Answer (score 2):

Any version of windows does not natively come with a clipboard manager. This means, that when you copy data to the clipboard any previously stored information is first deleted before the new information is stored there.

This means that windows will only remember 1 thing at a time.

If you want to have the ability to store multiple things in the clipboard, you will need to have a clipboard mamager. Some programs have a clipboard manager buildin, such as Microsoft office, but they tend to only work inside their program/suite.

Because of this, people have developed clipboard managers, which you can run in windows and allow you to paste any value that was copied earlier with additional options on how to manage them. Googling for `clipboard manager` will give you plenty results. I use ClipX myself for a very long time, with the additional Sticky plugin which allows me to preset certain information.

With such program copy/paste still works the same, but there's an additional method (shortcut-key or mouse action) that allows you to paste from the history.